# Есть ли смысл заниматься олимпиадным программированием?

Tags: php, олимпиада

Работаю веб-разработчиком (junior). Недавно проходил курс, где попалась олимпиадная задача. Решить ее смог, но решение было далеко от идеала (сверил с решением автора). Ну и задачи подобного формата мне даются сложно.

Поможет ли мне олимпиадное программирование в развитии программистких скиллов, если выделю 6-7 часов в неделю?

Хипстерские советы типа "Лучше подключись к open source проекту на github" не актуальны.

Какую литературу можете посоветовать?

Comment: А вы думаете, решение олимпиадных задач не хипстерство? Такое же хипстерство, только олдскульное.

Comment: Ваш вопрос мне очень нравится и я поддерживаю ваше увлечение. Но к сожалению тематике сайта он не соответствует, т.к. слишком субъективный и подвержен холиварам. Чтобы обсудить это в свободной форме, приходите вечером в чат. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Олимпиадное программирование даст вам хорошую эрудицию в алгоритмах и комбинаторике. В целом весьма полезные знания и умения. Задачи, требующие таких знаний, в реальной жизни бывают, но редко, зависит от наукоёмкости предметной области.

Сам по себе стиль в котором решаются олимпиадные задачи -- выполнить задачу хоть как, но уложиться в заданное время -- в обычном программировании чаще всего неприемлем: обычно тут нужно решить задачу с должным качеством, включая качество написанного кода, за приемлемое время. Причём важен навык оценки времени на разработку и способность уложиться в заявленное время. Понятность решения часто даже важнее производительности -- потому что если кроме вас в этом никто не разберётся, то всё равно перепишут "как проще".

Единственная ситуация в жизни, которая действительно похожа на олимпиадную -- это когда кто-то (чаще всего вы сами) накосячили на проде, и нужно срочно найти решение проблемы и пофиксить.

Успешным олимпиадникам на обычных проектах скучно -- мало мест где можно себя проявить, зато море рутины.

Comment: Причём успешные олимпиадчики часто не могут в читабельность и программный дизайн.

Comment: поспорил бы с вами, олимпиады дают хорошие навык писать тривиальные вещи не задумываясь и с 1 раза + сразу достаточно эффективно. Да, качество кода может страдать (например там скорее всего не будет ООП патернов и прочей _фигни_ которая замедляет код). 
Если вы хотите работать с big data или писать алгоритмы реального времени (например высокочастотная торговля) то олимпиады практически необходимы.

Но для веб-разработки смысла нет, судя по тегу php оно вам не надо.

Comment: не влезло продолжение...

Конкретно что именно развивает олимпиада зависит от самой олимпиады, например на codeforces "учат" быстро понимать чужой код и искать в нём ошибки.  Есть олимпиады типа марафон, там получается вполне приличный по качеству код. И так далее.

Comment: @pavel: Всякая _фигня_ типа ООП спасёт вас, если вы будете работать над неигрушечным проектом в несколько миллионов строк.

Comment: @pavel: А неподдерживаемый и нерасширяемый код, даже если он и решает конкретную задачу, всё равно никому не нужен.

Comment: Ну почему) написал модуль или функцию и забыли, используется как чёрный ящик, главного задокументировать.

Comment: @pavel это если Вы живёте в идеальном мире где пони какают радугой и ТЗ не меняется. Меня тут попросили помочь со скриптами к программе для проектирования мебели — надо было взять готовый скрипт и расширить функционал. В плане алгоритмов там всё тривиально, конечно. Трудности возникали только из-за незнания нюансов предметной области и ужасного кода — начиная с названий переменных (Krepej, Polka, x1, H1, YGL: последнее, как оказалось — "угол") и заканчивая отсутствием хоть какого-то структурирования кода (вынесение повторяющегося кода в функции). Автор, видимо, тоже "написал модуль и забыл".

Comment: @VladD это вы ещё не написали о том, как этот код деплоить и эксплуатировать. А там целый отдельный океан проблем. )